# emacs use-package org hook and config different

Tags: image, emacs, org-mode

1. I want to display image when emacs startup, i write up a function to setup and add it to use-package. But it doesn't work when add to :hook, it does work add it to :config.
   I'm wondering what is the different between add it to :hook and :config?

   ```
    (defun my/org-mode-startup ()
      (setq org-startup-with-inline-images t
            org-image-actual-width '(100)
            )
      )

    (use-package org
      :hook (org-mode . my/org-mode-startup)
      :config
      )
   ```
2. I want to set buffer-face-mode-face, I define a defvar and it doesn't work to use this variable in :height, it does work to use 150 number.

what is wrong use this variable?

(defvar my/default-font-size 150)

(setq buffer-face-mode-face '(:family "Courier New"
:height my/default-font-size
:width normal))

Comment: hook run every time org-mode is enabled, while config run when org is first loaded.

Comment: You should ask one question at a time.